# Azure Data Factory - How to force an Azure Machine Learning Pipeline to Refresh

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

Azure Data Factory - How to force an Azure Machine Learning Pipeline to Refresh?

I notice that Azure DF refreshes an Azure ML pipeline in 2 seconds, but it uses / returns cached results?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your pipeline with an image? any errors or blockers and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to run a successful pipeline again is to set `force_rerun` parameter under settings as `True`.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-yaml-job-pipeline?view=azureml-api-2#attributes-of-the-settings-key) is the documentation.

Example pipeline.yml file.

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineJob.schema.json
type: pipeline
display_name: MyFancyDisplayName

settings:
  force_rerun: True

...
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that works for prototyping a simple Azure ML pipeline that I want to refresh everytime I call it from Azure DF.

The 'trick' is to define an Azure ML Pipeline parameter, I called it RunID.

Then when I call this Azure ML pipeline from an Azure DF pipeline I pass in the RunID with the current yyyyMMddHHmmss.

This guarantees, in my case, that I pass in a unique RunID everyime Azure DF executes the Machine Learning Pipeline.

This - seems to force Azure ML to execute the pipeline, instead of using cached results.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer but the best practice is to use `force_rerun` parameter 
 like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78187496/11758585) instead of implementing a trick.